# SQL syntax error when using an api with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I got a response from guardian api, managed to load it into a variable, I am attempting to put the content into the relevant database table, but it comes up with the error below:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://content.guardianapis.com/?format=json&show-     fields=all&show-related=true&order-by=newest&show-most-viewed=true&api-    key=srty8vfmpgjhjakk4k6edbjb");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
$response_api = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

require_once 'Zend/Json.php'; 
$val = Zend_Json::decode($response_api); 
foreach ($val['response']['mostViewed'] as $result) {
$title = $result['webTitle']; 
$url = $result['webUrl'];
$body_text = $result['fields']['body'];
$title = utf8_decode($title);
$body_text = utf8_decode($body_text);


$sql="INSERT INTO news_data (title, content)
VALUES
('$title','$body_text')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Am I getting this error because there are strange characters within the article that I am trying to load into the certain variables and then onto my database?

Thanks

JB

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734004/mysql-syntax-error)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `news_data` (`title`, `content`)
VALUES
('".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($body_text)."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the outdated mysql extension and string concatenation, then you also need to apply [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on each string variable. That's `$title` and `$body_text` in your case. Otherwise a single single quote will make your INSERT query unparsable for the MySQL server. (And [potential security issues](http://bobby-tables.com/), bla bla...)